# I want to make this program more quickly

Tags: c

I was made this program
This program makes array which each digit is different
but it takes so much time

```
void generateArr() {
    int randomNum;
    int sameNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrScale; i++) {
        while (true)
        {
            sameNum = 0;
            srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
            randomNum = rand() % 10;
            for (int j = 0; j < arrScale; j++) {
                if (numArr[j] == randomNum) {
                    sameNum = 1;
                }
            }
            if (sameNum == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        numArr[i] = randomNum;
    }
}
```

numArr and arrScale is made in front

Comment: What do you mean by each digit is different? why do you use random? can you add an example of input and output please?

Comment: Don't call `srand` more than once during the whole program execution. Not only is it "wrong" - it also makes the program slower.

Comment: Instead of an array, use a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Then it's very fast to see collisions.

Comment: Make an array with all the digits. Then shuffle it randomly.

Comment: Ted Lyngmo 
Thank you!
Your answer was helpful

Comment: @limserhane You can take the first N elements of the array if you need fewer.

Comment: Break out of the inner loop when you set `sameNum = 1;`

Comment: @Schwern Since the array is at most 10 elements long, linear search will probably be faster than hashing.

Comment: @SupportUkraine When you get to the last element, it will probably generate lots of collisions before it picks the remaining available number. So it slows down considerably near the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a separate buffer `t` of size 10 and  whenever you draw `x`, set `t[x]` to 1. So you can evaluate `t[x] == 1` to check if `x` is already in your array and don't have to loop over it.

Note that your program won't work if your array has size greater than 10.

Comment: I don't think the loop is the bottleneck, it's the generate-and-test design.

Answer (score 2):

First: Don't call `srand` more than once per program run. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

In order to speed up generating the numbers, you could make sure that you never pick a number that's been picked before.

Example:

```c
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void generateArr() {
    for (int i = arrScale; i > 1; --i) {
        // pick a number never picked before and swap with the last number
        swap(numArr + (rand() % i), numArr + (i-1));
    }
}
```

Not only is it pretty fast - every possible permutation will have an equal chance of appearing (with the little detail that `rand() % i` is not uniformly distributed).